# How to use dynamic operator in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Am trying to use dynamic operator in mysql query..

```
select @customer_name:= 'like',customer_mobile 
from ps_customer 
WHERE firstname @customer_name 'ramesh';
```

But am not getting any result.. is this correct way to use like this.. or any other soutions...?

Comment: you can do server side using string concatenation  but  not  directly in sqlcommand .. (eg: i console or sql IDE)

Comment: No. What are you trying to do?

Comment: directly in mysql query trying to put variable which is assigned by comparative operarator..